# Javascript: self-executable classes and public functions

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of the following classes:

```
(function() {
   if (!window.Administration) {
     window.Administration = {};
   }
   window.Administration.Customers = (function() {
      // some code and private methods
      return {
      // public methods
      };
   })();
})();
```

I heard somewhere that such declarations of public methods are not so good because js engines create as many instances of public methods as you called them from the code... Is that true?

In this case how can I refactor my code in order to solve such memory leaks but leave the self-executable feature?

Thank you

Comment: How about simply refactoring the function definition into a separate expression?

Comment: This really depends on the goals of your code; if information hiding is important, you need this ... otherwise just bolt on the methods via the prototype and save some memory.

Comment: The question is how big such leaks are

Answer (score 0):

You could use this construct instead if you're only worried about hiding methods:

```
(function(ns) {

    // default constructor
    ns.Blah = function(v) {
        this.v = v;
        setup.call(this); // invoke private method
    }

    // private method, invoked using .call(this)
    function setup()
    {
        this.w = this.v + 123;
    }

    function myhello()
    {
        return 'w = ' + this.w + ' and v = ' + this.v;
    }

    ns.Blah.prototype = {
        hello: function() {
            return myhello.call(this);
        }
    };

}(window.MYNS = window.MYNS || {});
```

Comment: it's not about hiding methods... I want to save memory and remove such leaks if they really are

Comment: @nKognito Well, this would save memory; am I missing something?

Comment: @nkognito is that a requirement? :) the self executable is what hides the implementation but that's just one way.